# Semantic UI Popup does not show

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

Using semantic as front end and trying to use pop, but it will not shown the pop up

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui teal button" data-title="Using click events" data-content="Clicked popups will close if you click away, but not if you click inside the popup">Click Me</div>
    <div class="ui icon input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Focus me..." data-content="You can use me to enter data">
    <i class="search icon"></i>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $('.example .teal.button')
   .popup({
    on: 'click'
  })
;
$('.example input')
  .popup({
    on: 'focus'
  })
;
</script>
```

this is jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/ynaLoe4z/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You using wrong selectors in jQuery. Remove `.example` from selectors  and it work like a cham.

```js
    $('.teal.button')
      .popup({
        on: 'click'
      });
    $('input')
      .popup({
        on: 'focus'
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.7/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ui teal button" data-title="Using click events" data-content="Clicked popups will close if you click away, but not if you click inside the popup">Click Me</div>
<div class="ui icon input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Focus me..." data-content="You can use me to enter data">
  <i class="search icon"></i>
</div>
```

Here's fixed [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynaLoe4z/3/)

Comment: Haha, just because wrong selector. Thank you very much. One more question where is the selector  .teal.button come from.

Comment: @joseph-goh From classes `class="ui teal button"` dot `.` in selector means class as is css so if you write `$('.teal.button')` selector, this meands you selecting button with class `teal` and `button`

Comment: So if write $('.ui.teal.button') will having same result?

Comment: @joseph-goh yes, because div has all those three classes.

Answer (score 5):

Since semantic-ui 2.2 there are css-only popups available.

```
<div data-tooltip="Add your text here"></div>
```

You can also include other attributes such as `data-variation="mini"` to change the size.

http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/new.html